# CakePHP model that references itself

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have the following situation. I have a model that refers to a database table called `questions`.  The questions table contains a key reference called `parent_id`, so a question can have a parent. This parent is a question record in the same table. This is because some questions are really a bundle of questions that the end user needs to see together.

I have tried to model this behavior in my database as followed:

```
 public $hasMany = array(
    'AttemptedQuestions' => array( 'classname' =>   'AttemptedQuestions' ),
    'Questions' => array('className'=>'Questions', 'foreignKey'=>'parent_id')
);
```

Edit: So the weird thing is that in the questions controller I can reference my data just fine as followed:

```
$test_question = $this->Question->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => 25)));
```

This will do exactly what I want. I am returned an array of data that has a question and its children. Accessing as `$test_question['Questions']` for the questions `$test_question['Children']` for the questions that have the `parent_id` of the parent question. What I do not understand is that if I reference this model in another controller like `Tests`, it does not return the children's array. Only the questions part is returned. How is the data returned from the model dependent on the controller you are in? This behavior seems odd and I want to know how to get the children from the database as well. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @teresko This must be like the third time you have edited a question of mine. What did you edit here?

Comment: i removed the "mvc" tag and added "cakephp-appmodel" tag. First of all because CakePHP does not implement MVC nor any other MVC-inspired pattern. It actually just mimics (somewhat poorly) the Rails setup for PHP. And your question is actually about `AppModel` structure in CakePHP framework, which is [Active Record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) implementation.

Comment: @IamJohnGalt: You can see the revision history by clicking on the time of the last edit (http://i.imgur.com/Hbk1P3I.png)

Comment: @tereško That sounds like a subjective opinion. One based on a personal bias towards disliking CakePHP. I think CakePHP is a valid implementation of MVC. What leads you to believe otherwise?

Comment: This hs nothing to do with belief. Please, research the MVC pattern, and then compare to what CakePHP sells you are "mvc framework". If you do not know where to begin, start by looking up what are responsibilities of controller (try wikipedia).

Comment: Could it be because containable and/or recursive are set differently in those models/controllers? Or is the same for all the application (do note that containable sets recursive according to "your need", so maybe it deems the children useless unless you call them directly within the "contain" option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'classname' key has to match the model classname, it's not abritrary.  So:

```
class Question extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
       'ChildQuestion' => array('className'=>'Question', 'foreignKey'=>'parent_id')
    );
}
```

The $hasMany array key (i.e. "ChildQuestion") can be arbitrary; this will appear in the results.

---

Bonus: If you need to get the parent of a child question, add:

```
    public $belongsTo= array(
       'ParentQuestion' => array('className'=>'Question', 'foreignKey'=>'parent_id')
    );
```